# How to arrange images and video thumbnails into a tile like format in a web page?

Tags: html

I would like to arrange a few images and video thumbnail views into a tile like format (like the apps on windows 8 start screen) in a web page. Which tag should i use for this purpose and how to use them?

Comment: Your question title implies a singular tag, however you appear to be asking about two different features (the tile like format and the navigation menu).

Answer (score 1):

Generic website structure: `<div>`

Navigation menu: `<ul>` / `<li>`

Menu should be in ULs for easier browsing (using text-based browsers and readers for blind people) as well as google compatibility. Your tiles are nothing extraordinary, just a type of layout, and layout should be made using divs.

(And for a love of god - if you have a tabular data on your website: put it in tables, cause each time someone creates a table out of divs: a cute kitty dies)

The only exception from this are HTML5 websites - out there it's bit more complicated. You have tags like `header`, `nav`, `figure` etc.

For HTML5 layout implementation you should read [one of HTML5 coding guides](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/04/designing-a-html-5-layout-from-scratch/).

Answer (score 0):

Almost all placement of elements on modern web pages is done via the `<div>` tag and CSS rules.